# ( Javascript ) is Hash Map or Set best represented by Const or Let variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory, hashtable

I wanted to ask the community when declaring a `new Map()` or `new Set()` in javascript, do you assign `const` or `let` keyword?

```
const map = new Map()
vs
let map = new Map()
```

I know that both `const` and `let` will work fine because it's allocating space in memory for the hash table but I wonder if there's any benefit to use either or.
Does it even matter at the end of the day?

Comment: no difference between the two really aside from semantics and scope. Use whichever one fits your use case. There is no performance impact from either.

Comment: Don't think there's any, but better to use `const`, so that you don't accidentally re assign  the same name somewhere in your code.